# Why can't a smart pointer call new() for me in its constructor?

Tags: c++, memory-management, smart-pointers

Is it possible to write a smart pointer which allocates the object itself in its constructor - instead of the developer having to call `new`?  In other words, instead of writing:

`std::unique_ptr<myClass> my_ptr(new myClass(arg1, arg2))`

...one could write:

`std::smarter_ptr<myClass> my_ptr(arg1, arg2)`

Is the language syntax capable of expressing this?  Would this be desirable?  Hideous?  I'm thinking in particular of protecting against this mistake (which I've made myself, of course):

`myFunction(std::unique_ptr<myClass>(new myClass()), std::unique_ptr<myClass>(new myClass()))`

...which risks leaking whichever object is allocated first if the second allocation happens and throws before the first object is safely ensconced in its smart pointer.  But would a smarter pointer actually make this safe?

Comment: @Joe: It is a concern; it's quite possible for the generated code to execute the two `new` expressions before using either result to initialise a smart pointer; in which case you will get a leak if the second one throws.

Comment: @Joe: You're wrong.  `tmp1 = new myClass(); tmp2 = new myClass(); arg1 = std::unique_ptr(tmp1); arg2 = std::unique_ptr(tmp2); myFunction(arg1, arg2);` is a perfectly legal execution order.

Comment: Fair enough, I was probing to prove myself incorrect. Thanks.

Comment: @Joe, see [GOTW #56](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/056.htm)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: let's update the references [GotW #102](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look at the implementation of [`make_shared()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared). It does this allocates a new object and creates a [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) out of it.

Comment: Excellent - it even saves an allocation. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 11):

In general, this can't be done with a smart pointer's constructor; there would be an ambiguity over whether a pointer argument should be used to initalise the smart pointer, or forwarded to create a new object.

It can be done with a factory function, for example:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args) {
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

If you're using `std::shared_ptr`, then you can use `std::make_shared`. This also gives the advantage of only requiring one memory allocation, where `std::shared_ptr<T>(new T)` will require one for the object and a second for the shared reference count.

Comment: Surely the ambiguity would only exist if the feature were added to existing smart pointers, no?  I'm still curious about why they weren't implemented like `make_shared()` to start with; there's an asymmetry that bugs me in having the smart pointer call `delete` but having to call `new` oneself.

Answer (score 2):

This is newly possible with C++11 which added [perfect forwarding](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/rvalue_references_and_perfect_forwarding.html) and variadic templates.

Answer (score 2):

It's essentially the same problem that necessitate `std::find` and `std::find_if`. You can't distinguish this ctor from the existing ctors of `shared_ptr` in the `new myClass(arg1)` case. The number of arguments is equal, and `arg1` can have any type.

Therefore, you need another name, and that's `make_shared`

Comment: This is easily solvable with tag types, like `shared_ptr<T>(std::inplace_args, args...)`, which is also what the standard does for passing allocator arguments to certain variadic functions.

Comment: @Xeo, true, so `make_shared` isn't essential, it could have been done as the OP suggests, but `make_shared<T>(args...)` is less typing anyway :)

Comment: @Xeo: Indeed. There are many possible solutions, and C++ isn't entirely consistent.